# How Java isAbsolute() depends on path separator and/or OS?

Tags: java, path, absolute-path

I'm trying to correct some code written in Java.
Back and forward slashes behave differently in isAbsolute() function.

```
Path ESPath = Paths.get("\\es-module-repo\\fdea3319-18ea-4bd5-8ae2-2662d6f2ba72\\foo.mjs");
if (ESPath.isAbsolute()) { ... }
Path ESPath2 = Paths.get("/es-module-repo/fdea3319-18ea-4bd5-8ae2-2662d6f2ba72/foo.mjs");
if (ESPath2.isAbsolute()) { ... }
```

But does this depends on OS on which Java is running?
[This code](https://ideone.com/lMHSeE) shows the difference.
Is the path (which one?) actually absolute or not?
So, what is the safest method to transfer backslashes (actually double backslashes) to forward slashes? And is it correct to do that?

EDIT: I'm working on a Windows machine and have the first case, which returns `false`.

Comment: from the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/nio/file/FileSystem.html#getPath(java.lang.String,java.lang.String...)) of `getPath()`, used to created the `Path`: "*The parsing and conversion to a path object is inherently implementation dependent.*"

Comment: On Windows neither path is absolute - absolute paths on Windows must include the drive letter.

Comment: @ThomasKläger Understood the 2nd path is absolute on a Linux machine and the whole code is not portable to Windows?

Comment: Depends on how you define "portable": on [Windows](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/io/file-path-formats) an absolute path has either the form C:\path\to\something or \\server\share\path\to\something (or as Java strings: `"C:\\path\\to\\something"` and `"\\\\server\\share\\path\\to\\something"`) and for these paths `Path.isAbsolute()` returns true. And the Java parser for Windows paths also accepts the forward slash: `"C:/path/to/something"` and `"//server/share/path/to/something"` represent the same two paths and for these paths `Path.isAbsolute()` also returns true.

Answer (score 0):

Java on Windows recognises both forms of slash `/` and backslash `\` as file separator, so you will find that on Windows `ESPath.equals(ESPath2)` is `true` because they contain the same relative path and they both have 3 components - see `ESPath.getNameCount()`.

See comments by @ThomasKläger. Windows will report `ESPath/ESPath2.isAbsolute()` as false because there is no drive letter. When you call `ESPath.toAbsolutePath()` Windows will return absolute path prefixing your paths with the current drive letter that applied at the time you started the JVM, and so would resolve to different locations if you ran:

```
cd /d c:\SomeDir
java YourApp

cd /d d:\AnotherDir
java YourApp
```

Your "This code" link shows the GNU/Linux handling which is different compared to Windows as it only recognises slash `/` as a path separator, and treats backslash `\` as yet another character of the filename. Try:

```
touch a\\b\\c
=> creates a file called a\b\c in current directory
```

Thus you will find that `ESPath.equals(ESPath2)` is `false`, `ESPath.isAbsolute()` is `false` as `ESPath.getNameCount()` shows only one path component, whereas `ESPath2.getNameCount()` is 3 and `ESPath2.isAbsolute()` is `true` because the path starts with `/`.

Answer (score 0):

I started a debugging process and used the *Force Step Into* command to derive the in-equality.

The first path, *ESPath*, is using the *[UnixPath#isAbsolute](https://github.com/openjdk/jdk/blob/master/src/java.base/unix/classes/sun/nio/fs/UnixPath.java#L359)* method.

Which, is yielding a *false* on the second condition, here.
Whereas, *ESPath2* is yielding a *true*, for both.

```java
@Override
public boolean isAbsolute() {
    return (path.length > 0 && path[0] == '/');
}
```

Furthermore, the *[Paths](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/nio/file/Paths.html)* JavaDoc has the following *@apiNote* recommendation.

```java
/**
 * @apiNote
 * It is recommended to obtain a {@code Path} via the {@code Path.of} methods
 * instead of via the {@code get} methods defined in this class as this class
 * may be deprecated in a future release.
 */
```